# PHP Distributed File System, File System for downloading from Network Storage

Tags: php, filesystems, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have network storage which is available for me. My job is to create script which will daily download updated files from this storage ( file to download have same name just content is different).

And here is question to You because I'm not very experienced in writing scripts ( only `php` and little bit `sh`).

I tried using `samba` and class which is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smbwebclient/) but this class is supposed to create `UI` to download files manually which is not what I am looking for.

Can You please tell me any other way how can I download files from network storage?

Comment: I use PHP copy function to copy files from remote servers.   It works for downloading everything from HTML files to multi-megabyte zips.  Perhaps this with a Cronjob to automate it?

Comment: yes cron is the only solution for automation I can think of, about copy function im going to test it right now

Answer (score 0):

Network file system, using PHP and MongoDB

http://verens.com/2014/11/06/distributed-file-storage-using-php-and-mongodb/